# Extract array of key-values from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

How can I generate an array of a certain key-value pair from a nested JS object? Is there a lodash function to do this kind of thing?

**Original data**

```
{
  "data": {
    "allLecturesJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "index": 1,
            "date": "01/02/2018",
            "presenter": "Mary",
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "index": 2,
            "date": "01/03/2018",
            "presenter": "Jack",
          }
        },
  }
}
```

**Expected result**

```
[
  {
    "index": 1,
    "date": "01/02/2018",
    "presenter": "Mary",
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "date": "01/03/2018",
    "presenter": "Jack"
  }
]
```

Comment: I added answer, hope it will work as per your expectation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jsonData.data.allLecturesJson.edges.map(e => e.node)
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your data is not well formatted. You have to format that to a valid object.

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Try the following way with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var jsonData = {
  "data": {
    "allLecturesJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "index": 1,
            "date": "01/02/2018",
            "presenter": "Mary",
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "index": 2,
            "date": "01/03/2018",
            "presenter": "Jack",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

var resArr = jsonData.data.allLecturesJson.edges.map(i => i.node);
console.log(resArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the required data structure. No need to use lodash :)

Here is a function which transforms the structure:

```
const input = {
  "data": {
    "allLecturesJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "index": 1,
            "date": "01/02/2018",
            "presenter": "Mary",
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "index": 2,
            "date": "01/03/2018",
            "presenter": "Jack",
          }
        }]
  }
}};

const output = input.data.allLecturesJson.edges.reduce((accumulator, currVal) => {
  return [...accumulator, currVal.node];
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with single line of code using `Array.map()` method with `Arrow` function expression.

**Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "data": {
    "allLecturesJson": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "index": 1,
            "date": "01/02/2018",
            "presenter": "Mary",
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "index": 2,
            "date": "01/03/2018",
            "presenter": "Jack",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

var res = jsonObj.data.allLecturesJson.edges.map(obj => obj.node);

console.log(res);
```